# Grant read permission to only document creator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to create valid security rules to allow listing all docs from `subscriptions` collection with their contents, which currently logged in user happens to own? And also make possible editing those docs by the same person, with few additional validation rules?

Firebase documentation has very poor examples from time to time. This is what I've tried so far, but it says I have insufficient permissions to read or write:

```
match /subscriptions {

  allow list;

  match /{id} {
    allow read: if resource.data.user == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.sub);

    allow update: if request.resource.data.user == request.auth.sub
                  && request.resource.data.user == resource.data.user
                  && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['code', 'schedules', 'common'])
                  && request.resource.data.code is string
                  && request.resource.data.schedules is list
                  && request.resource.data.common is bool;
  }

}
```

One *subscription* can only have one *user* defined, so in terms of that, I could use subcollection inside user documents. But because I have to process all hundreds – possibly thousands of – subscriptions in one, it would be pretty inefficient to fetch every user and every subscription one by one. So now I have `subscriptions` collection in the root of the database.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using `request.auth.sub` and not `request.auth.uid` ?

Comment: That's a great question. Looks like I've misread this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties